# Добавить номер строки в конец строки

Tags: bash

Есть несколько файлов с разным количеством строк. Нужно пронумеровать строки,
указав номер строки в конце этой строки.

```
cat temp1
отчет ноябрь
отчет декабрь
```

Ожидаемый результат

```
cat temp2
отчет ноябрь [1]
отчет декабрь [2]
```

Пробовал for, но ожидаемый результат получить не удалось.

Comment: Приложите вашу попытку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если под «*Bash*» вы подразумеваете
«*shell*-скрипт», то можно с помощью *Awk*:

```sh
awk '{print($0 " [" NR "]")}' ./tmp.txt
```

Чтобы заменить содержимое файла вместо вывода
в `stdout`:

```sh
awk '{print($0 " [" NR "]")}' ./tmp.txt | sponge ./tmp.txt
```

На самом же *Bash* это будет как-то так:

```sh
i=1
while read -r line
do
	echo "$line [$i]"
	((i++))
done
```